# Is there any process to check whether a data set has index or not?

Tags: sas

A few of my datasets get generated by other team and I use them in my process using the index merging. Is there any way to check whether those datasets has already indexed, if indexed, on which variables they indexed?

Comment: Yes. You can check if the dataset has indexes (indices?) with Proc contents     proc **contents data=My_data  out = contents; run;** I've never done merging by these indexes, but that's how you can find them.

Answer (score 5):

The standard view SASHELP.VINDEX lists all datasets that have indexes along with the name of the index, the names of the indexed variables and the type of index. This view contains one record per indexed table and indexed variable

You can simply query that view to check if a record exists for these datasets and, if so, to see what variables are indexed.